# Import into dicts

Tags: python, dictionary

I need to add items into my dict:

```
ingred_list.update({'item': 'value'})
```

But I want to add the value contained in the variables 'item' and 'value'. 
Can I use .get? How?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove quotes if `item` and `value` are live variable in your code.

e.g.

```
>>> item = "b"
>>> value = "b2"
>>> d1 = {"a":"1a"}
>>> d1.update({'item': 'value'})
>>> d1
{'a': '1a', 'item': 'value'}
>>> d1.update({item: value})
>>> d1
{'a': '1a', 'item': 'value', 'b': 'b2'}
>>>
```

---

[Update method of dictionary](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html).

Update the dictionary with the key/value pairs from other, overwriting existing keys. Return None.
update() accepts either another dictionary object or an iterable of key/value pairs (as tuples or other iterables of length two).

e.g.

```
>>> d2 = {"a": 1, "b": 2}
>>> d1 = {"c": 3}
>>> d1.update(d2)
>>> d1
{'a': 1, 'c': 3, 'b': 2}
```

If keyword arguments are specified, the dictionary is then updated with those key/value pairs:

e.g.

```
>>> d1 = {"c": 3}
>>> d1.update(a=1, b=2)
>>> d1
{'a': 1, 'c': 3, 'b': 2}
```

---

Set key and value into dictionary.

This will create new key if key is not present in dictionary and assign value to it. If key is present then this will replace value with new value.

e.g.

```
>>> d1 = {"c": 3}
>>> d1["e"] = 5
>>> d1
{'c': 3, 'e': 5}
>>> d1["e"] = 6
>>> d1
{'c': 3, 'e': 6}
>>>
```

Comment: @AmyMagoria: answer is updated.. I can be reached anytime via email at vivekbsable@gmail.com, for my skype id: vivek.igp.

Answer (score 2):

Just remove the single quotes which was around `item` and `value`. Python treats anything which was present inside a single quotes or double quotes as a string.

```
ingred_list.update({item: value})
```

**Example:**

```
>>> d = {}
>>> item = 1
>>> val = 2
>>> d.update({item:val})
>>> d
{1: 2}
```

Comment: No, update will add all keys and values from the dictionary to target dictionary. Update method take dictionary as argument.

Comment: @AmyMagoria no, update add an new item to a dictionary but the above replace the value of a particular key with another.

Answer (score 1):

Simple way:

```
dict1 = {}
item = 'obama'
val = 'president'
dict1.update({item:val})
print dict1
```